# dynamic class in AS3 : listening to property creation?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm currently working on a project that involve a re-implementation of the Array class. 
This object needs to be an Array for compatibility reasons, while I also need to keep control of what is written in.

I cannot seem to find any way to check property creation inside of a dynamic object in AS3. Something that would work like the Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE but, like, ClassEvent.PROPERTY_ADDED.

I override methods like push, splice etc, but I cannot control direct assignation : MyArray[i] = ...

Is such a thing even possible ?

Of course, I could make some kind of validations elsewhere, but this would involve accessing a part of the code I cannot modify.

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow you entirely but you may be looking for the Proxy class:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Proxy.html

An example at the bottom shows you how you can override direct assignment:

```
override flash_proxy function setProperty(name:*, value:*):void {
    _item[name] = value;
}
```

Using this you would be able to dispatch a custom event that would be fired any time an item was added to your ProxyArray

Comment: Yeah, this is the way to do it. Just remember, though, the Proxy class is black magic. _Everything_ goes through its methods, so be careful referring to instance variables or methods from inside of `flash_proxy` methods.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for ! thanks a lot, you saved my day :)
@TK Kocheran : Ill make some test with Proxies, but does that mean in-class property declaration ( public var boo:... ) are also going through those methods ? And so on all inherited properties ? I'm not sure it make sense, but if true it's almost impossible to make the difference between the two contexts..